# Backbone.Marionette CollectionView/CompositeView rendering

Tags: marionette

This question is an extension of this [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160421/how-to-render-view-with-backbone-marionette).

Taking Derick's advice, I now have my data in the correct shape. i.e. I have a collection of `Department` objects, each of which have a collection of `Users`.

Again following Derick's advice I'm trying to render a `CollectionView` of `CompositeView`'s

My collection view looks like this

```
class UserListView extends Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView
    itemView: UserCompositeView
    id: "user-list"  

    appendHtml: (collectionView, itemView, index) =>
      itemModel = @collection.at(index)
      itemView = new UserCompositeView
        model: itemModel 
        collection: itemModel.get("users")

      collectionView.$el.append itemView.el
```

and my `Composite View` looks like this:

```
  class UserCompositeView extends Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView
    itemView: UserItemView
    itemViewContainer: '#users'
```

If I don't override the appendHtml method then the view renders but it only renders the properties of the `Department` model. It doesn't render the `users` collection.

When I override the `appendHtml` method in the `CollectionView` so I can pass a model (a `Department` object) and a collection of `users` but one or both of them seem to be the wrong type of objects because the `Marionette bindTo` function is complaining that the object has no 'on' method.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does `itemModel.get("users")` return?

If this is returning a JavaScript array or object literal, that would be the problem. You have to pass a valid Backbone.Collection as the collection parameter, not just an array of objects.

`collection: new Backbone.Collection(itemModel.get("users"))`

Comment: Thanks Derick, yes I discovered this was the problem yesterday. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into using [backbone-relational](http://backbonerelational.org/) which will let you define models that have submodels or subcollections.